# How to use async custom hook in Next.js middleware?

Tags: next.js

I have this custom hook:

```
const useRedirects = async () => {

    const response = await fetch('/redirect/list') 
    const redirects = await response.json()

    const checkRedirection = (url) => {
       return {
           isRedirected: // logic to check redirection
           newUrl: // logic to form the new URL
       }
    }

    return {
        checkRedirection
    }
}

export default useRedirects
```

And this is my `middleware.js` code:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { useRedirect } from './UseRedirect'

export async function middleware(request) {

    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next')) {
        return
    }

    const checkRedirection = await useRedirect()

    const { isRedirected, newUrl } = checkRedirection(request.nextUrl)
    
    if (isRedirected) {
       return newUrl
    }
}
```

The problem is that, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
> at eval (webpack-internal:///../../next/node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/error-overlay/hot-dev-client.js:262:55)
> error - ../next/node_modules/@emotion/cache/dist/emotion-cache.browser.esm.js (461:0) @ 
> error - document is not defined

So, how can I use an async hook inside my next.js middleware?

Comment: I am not sure if hooks can be using inside of NextJS middleware make just use a normal async function.

Comment: @JonathanDsouza, I created an async function inside my middleware, but it made no difference.

Comment: From the code you shared, the `useRedirects` is not a hook - it's just a regular function. Can you show us the full logic you have inside `checkRedirection`?